# sql query insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I insert multiple values in 2 tables? I thought something like this, but that obviously doesn't work:

```
insert into login as l,
      klantGegevens as k
      (l.password, 
       l.rechten, 
       l.status, 
       k.voornaam, 
       k.achternaam, 
       k.woonplaats, 
       k.postcode, 
       k.telefoonnr)
   values
      ('test',
        1,
        1,
        'niels',
        'jansen',
        'Amsterdam',
        '5993hk',
        0623232323)
```

EDIT:

```
 string intoDatabase = "insert into login  (password,rechten,status) values(@password,@rechten,@status) insert into klantGegevens (voornaam,achternaam,woonplaats,postcode,telefoonnr) values(@voornaam,@achternaam,@woonplaats,@postcode,@telefoonnr)";
```

Comment: you could ue a transaction to make sure that one won't be executed before the other

Answer (score 1):

Only in separate commands :

```
insert into login  (password,rechten,status) 
values('test',1,1)

insert into klantGegevens(voornaam,achternaam,woonplaats,postcode,telefoonnr) 
values('niels','jansen','Amsterdam','5993hk',0623232323)
```

Comment: @jarlh No, it doesn't :)

Comment: should have been a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, what's the best way for doing this in c#? See my edit.

Comment: @Jenssen You have to do it in two separate commands, maybe in transaction.